# Refresh Section in the page not the entire Page

Tags: jquery

Refresh the particular section, not the entire page.
I have sections in the html page, when i click the submit button the data is submitting, but i want to refresh container/section not the entire page.

I tried with the below.

```
$window.location.reload();
```

This one is refreshing the whole page.

```
$('#SectionId').load(document.URL + ' #SectionId');
```

this one is not working.

It should refresh the above mentioned section with the SectionId

Comment: what includes that Section? you can do it using ajax.

Comment: The jQuery [.load method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) attaches the entire document to the specified element. Web servers ignore the hash (`#`) fragment in URLs. They return the entire document. They will not return only a section of a document.

Comment: you mentioned a submit button. are you using a form element?

Comment: When i click a link, it will open the popup which comes from other js file, the popup has submit button, when the data is submitted from the popup, then that particular section needs to updated with the entered data.

Comment: by submit button you mean <input type="submit"> or some other button